# How to use pango in script with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, pango

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm currently using :

```
cat $FILES | while read line; do
     convert -fill $FG_COLOR -background $BG_COLOR \
         -size ${line_width}x${line_height} -page +${x_margin}+${y} \
         label:"${varL} and ${varR}" miff:-
done | convert -size ${SCREEN_W}x${SCREEN_H} xc:$BG_COLOR - -flatten image.jpg
```

And it is working well !

But I wish to have different colors for `${varL}` and `${varR}`, and I guess I should use `pango` instead of `label`. Am I correct about that ?

But by keeping the same code and just replacing `label` by `pango` I have an unexpected error :

```
convert-im6.q16: width or height exceeds limit
```

Comment: How large its the `${line_width}x${line_height}` variables?

Comment: Be sure to enclose shell variables in double quotes to avoid problems with colours like `rgb(0,0,0)` and filenames with spaces giving problems with expansion. I mean `convert -fill "$FG_COLOR" -background "$BG_COLOR" ...`

Comment: Colors are simple, like "black" or "white" but thanks for the advice. ${line_width}x${line_height} is ~785x14, doesn't seems excessive... page is about `+10+336` or so

Comment: If I remove the `-size ...` there is no error but also just a blank line with no text, and putting `pango':<span foreground="red">TEST</span>'` doesn't change anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very confused about how I was able to solve this.

Anyway here is the thing : I don't know why but pango needs to be BEFORE the other arguments.

```
convert -fill $FG_COLOR -background $BG_COLOR \
         -size ${line_width}x${line_height} -page +${x_margin}+${y} \
         pango:"${varL} and ${varR}" miff:-
```

Isn't working, but :

```
convert pango:"${varL} and ${varR}" \
         -fill $FG_COLOR -background $BG_COLOR \
         -size ${line_width}x${line_height} -page +${x_margin}+${y} miff:-
```

Is working !

EDIT: `pango:` need to be before `-page`